# How to join three DStreams in Spark streaming using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have three kafka producers which are sending data streams on the same topic at random intervals between 5-10 seconds. There is a  Spark consumer (python based ) which is consuming the data.

The requirement is to first separate the incoming stream into 3 separate streams in the consumer and then join them on the basis of a column. The producers are developed using Python.

I have been successfully able to divide the incoming datastream into 3 separate streams in Python. However, I face the issue in joining all 3 back together based on a key, which is the first value in the incoming data stream.

When I am joining 2 streams, the join is working as expected. 
However, when I am joining all 3 streams, I am not getting any output.

```
P1.LeftOuterJoin(P2) # works
P1.LeftOuterJoin(P3) # works
P2.Join(P3) # works

P1.LeftOuterJoin(P2.Join(P3)) # no output coming up
```